# Transfering a file from Windows to Linux (without network connection) over serial port

Tags: linux, windows, file-transfer

I have a Windows 7 machine which is connected to a linux prototyping board over a serial connection.

Now, I want to transfer files to Linux from Windows. The Linux machine does not have an additional network connection except for serial and the programs `rz`, `sz`, `screen` and `tmux` are not installed. Moreover, the `serial` python lib is also not installed.

Now I thought I could open PuTTY on Windows, connect to the Linux machine. Then run `nohup cat /dev/ttyMDF2 > receiving-file` and then close PuTTY on Windows to open the serial port up for connection again. Then run `copy test.file /B COM4: /B` on the Windows machine to send the file. Unfortunately, the file stays empty on the Linux machine.

How can I successfully transfer files to my Linux machine over a serial connection?

Thank you!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/278483/file-transfer-over-a-serial-line Teraterm, for instance, supports multiple transfer protocols.

Comment: yes, however the problem is that the Linux machine does not have kermit z/x/y modem installed and thus does not support receiving files using those protocols.

Comment: What programs are installed? Is there a compiler on the linux system?

Comment: yes, gcc is installed

Comment: Have you thought about using a memory stick or external hard drive?

Comment: Do you have the `busybox rx` command on your Linux system?

Answer (score 1):

For a small text file, `cat > somefile` and use the terminal's paste functionality to drop the file in. Hit `^D` at the end.

For binary files, you probably want to base64 encode it first, then decode on the remote with `base64 -d somefile.encoded > somefile`. Assuming you have `base64`. You'll have to do the encoding on the Windows side in some way.

For larger files, pasting to the terminal might not work, so you'll need something meant for reading files. Putty doesn't seem to have a function for dumping a file on the connection, some other terminal program might have. Though the command line tool `plink`, which comes with Putty, has the `-m` option to read "commands" from a file. It seems to work here. With this `foo.txt`:

```
cat > foo.out <<EOF
adsf
EOF
```

Running `plink -m foo.txt itvirta@somehost` created the file nicely. (Over SSH, but there shouldn't be a reason why a serial connection would be different.) With `base64`, you could skip the cat:

```
base64 -d <<EOF > outputfile
(base64 encoded data...)
EOF
```